Docker image increased in size after reducing the number of layers
I read that merging docker layers and removing unnecessary packages should reduce the size of final images.
I have this Dockerfile that is producing an image with 14 layers as per docker inspect and a size of 583MB:
FROM tomcat:9.0-jdk17-temurin-jammy
RUN <<-EOF
  set -e
  echo 'org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE=org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource' >> ./conf/catalina.properties
  mkdir -p /usr/local/tomcat/temp/Reports /usr/local/tomcat/temp/File_Import/ /var/log/mylog/
  apt-get update && apt-get install -y nano-tiny \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
EOF
COPY Artefacts/Portal/context.xml Artefacts/Portal/server.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
COPY Artefacts/Portal/*.jar /usr/local/tomcat/lib/
COPY Artefacts/Portal/myapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY Artefacts/Portal/SelfSigned.jks /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=5s --start-period=30s --retries=10 \
  CMD curl --fail --silent --insecure https://localhost:443/myapp/ || exit 1
ENV CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms2G -Xmx2G"
EXPOSE 443 8443 8080

To reduce the size, I tried to refactor it, removing unneeded packages and merging COPY and RUN layers with the following Dockerfile (same base image, layers = 11, size = 736MB)
FROM tomcat:9.0-jdk17-temurin-jammy
COPY Artefacts/Portal /tmp/
RUN <<-EOF
  set -eux
  echo 'org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE=org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource' >> ./conf/catalina.properties
  mkdir -p /usr/local/tomcat/temp/Reports /usr/local/tomcat/temp/File_Import/ /var/log/mylog/
  mv /tmp/*.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
  mv /tmp/*.jar /usr/local/tomcat/lib/
  mv /tmp/SelfSigned.jks /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
  mv /tmp/myapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
EOF
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=5s --start-period=30s --retries=10 \
  CMD curl --fail --silent --insecure https://localhost:443/myapp/ || exit 1
ENV CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms2G -Xmx2G"
EXPOSE 443 8443 8080

Notice that I now issue one COPY to /tmp and then move the files in the already-existing RUN layer. This removed 3 layers.
However, to my surprise the size increased.
What am I doing wrong? I am using Docker version 27.2.0, build 3ab4256 on Apple M1.

I drilled into the new image using docker history --human and saw:
<missing>             8 minutes ago   RUN /bin/sh -c   set -eux
  echo 'org.apache…   153MB           buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>             8 minutes ago   COPY Artefacts/Portal /tmp/ # buildkit          153MB     buildkit.dockerfile.v0

So 153MB are introduced in the RUN layer now because RUN has to mv the COPYied files to their places, and hence its size goes up.
In the first Dockerfile, multiple COPY commands put the files in their final places. My hypothesis was if I use one COPY to /tmp/ and then reuse the already-existing RUN to mv these files, I would be eliminating 3 COPY layers and the size of the final image should be reduced.
I was wrong, as I inflated the size of the RUN layer by adding a new responsibility to it: making it move around the COPYied files.

The incremental cost of a layer is approximately zero.  In some cases there can be some benefit from combining RUN instructions (especially, if you have two commands that create some sort of temporary file and then rm it, then they pretty much need to be in the same RUN line) but there's almost no intrinsic benefit from combining COPYs.

Yet many articles advocate that which gave me the wrong impression that less layers = less size

Most of the advice in that link is sound, beyond the section advocating combining layers for their own sake.  The other misconception that you can get from a quick read-through is that multi-stage builds are always smaller, and that's only true if there's something you can leave out of the final image (in the article it's omitting build-time Node devDependencies but that's not obvious).
